# Accessing to the zero position with a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

Why can't we access for exemple position zero(0), one hundred(100),
two hundred(200) in the memory;

Ex:

```
void main() {
    int* a;
    a = 0;
    printf("what is inside position o %d",*a);

}
```

Comment: Because for most modern multi-processing operating systems, the operating system's memory management subsystem carefully ensures that the first page (often 1024 or 4096 bytes) of memory is invalid and cannot be read or written (or executed).  And, for those systems, the typical response is a segmentation fault (possibly with core dump).  In the bad old days, DEC VAX systems allowed you to read (and write?) to memory location zero; programs developed for a VAX did not necessarily run well anywhere else because of that.

Comment: See also [The Ten Commandments for C Programmers (Annotated Edition)](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ten-commandments.html)).

Comment: You already answered my question!
thank you

Comment: @JonathanLeffler while I agree with what you commented but there is a difference between accessing the address 0 (all bits zero) and casting the integer zero to an address. While the second is explicitly disallowed by the standard, the first is allowed by the standard but disallowed by the implementations.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: I'm not sure I understand what you're claiming.  A pointer constant of zero is a null pointer.  A given machine might use a different (not all bits zero) representation for a null pointer, but at the source code level, if you assign a null pointer constant, you use an 'all bits zero' value, and the compiler's job is to make it work correctly on the hardware it is compiling for.  C programs (outside of a very small section of the o/s kernel) deal with virtual addresses.  And on typical desktop systems, reading or writing in (virtual) page 0 leads to segmentation faults.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what I meant is OP has done `a=0;`. After this operation `a` might not have all 0 bits and hence might not be in the first page like you explained in your comment. The compiler could assign the bit representation of `100000000000` (4096) for `NULL`. But it would still be invalid because it is dereferencing a NULL pointer. Addresses and pages are a part of the implementation. Even on your example of DEC VAX (which allows reading/writing to page 0), this program would be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter [§6.5.3.2p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4)

> `...` If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is **undefined**.

Quoting `C11`, chapter [§note102](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note102)

> `...` Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator are a **null pointer**, an address `...`

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

Also,

Quoting `C11`, chapter [§6.3.2.3p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3)

> An integer constant expression with the value `0`, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

You are thus trying to dereference a null pointer, the behavior of which has been explicitly said to be Undefined by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `*(char*)NULL` being undefined behavior, as [Ajay Brahmakshatriya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52879452/2445184) correctly points out, there is another reason why this won't work on any sane system: The linker and/or system kernel usually make special provisions to ensure that no accessible memory is ever mapped at address zero.

As such, any attempt to dereference a null-pointer will invariably trigger a *hardware* exception because there simply is no memory that the hardware could access. This hardware exception directly alerts the system's kernel about the condition, and the system's kernel usually reacts by killing the process with a segmentation fault.

The reason for this is that accidentally dereferencing a null-pointer is a really common mistake, and that it is generally not advisable to let a process continue doing possibly harmful stuff after it already entered the territory of undefined behavior. An immediate crash of the process is generally seen as the smaller evil. And it makes debugging of null-pointer accesses so much easier: If the process is being executed under a debugger, the debugger will directly point the programmer to the exact line that tried to dereference a null-pointer. The only thing that's left for the programmer to do, is to figure out *why* that line tried to dereference a null-pointer, and *where* the actual logical mistake was. This is much easier than with other forms of undefined behavior where the symptoms may appear at some fully unrelated location in the program.